# How to get Android Mobile contacts synced with my Web Server Database

Tags: java, android, android-adapter

I am loking for a account syncing with Android Account then getting contact from the phone to the Server. I have gone through certain links for the same but they have not helped me much. So need some help for this, as I am a beginner for this all concept, its quite similar concept that app like whatsapp picks up the contact list from the phone and it sits in the "account and sync" in the setting of android phone.

Links for this : [http://udinic.wordpress.com/2013/07/24/write-your-own-android-sync-adapter/]

Answer (score 0):

step 1 : store your contacts in some collection object

step 2 : apply some listener on your collection object ,whenever is it updated

step 3 : whenever contacts is updated set a flag value

step 4 : write a webservice to update contacts list

step 5 : if the flag value says updated , send newly added contacts via web service to the web server

step 6 : add the new contacts in your web server

Comment: I want it through "Account & Sync" service in Android so that my app can sit in the background for some other things may be. I have already posted the contacts to the server but I want to use "Account & Sync" service specifically.